EstimaterSize registry entry is not usd on Windows11
I am making NSIS installer and I want the size of the app (ideally, without the size of one subfolder that is installed inside) to be visible in the "Installed Apps" menu.
I have found multiple sources of the same solution:
!include "LogicLib.nsh" 
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!insertmacro GetSize
RequestExecutionLevel admin
${GetSize} "$INSTDIR" "/S=0K" $0 $1 $2
IntFmt $0 "0x%08X" $0
WriteRegDword HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyApp" "EstimatedSize" $0

It does something, apparently, as I can see the size information by actually checking the registry. However, it is still not shown in the "Installed Apps" on my Windows 11.

My guess is that is something wrong with Windows 11 rather than with code itself... The mentions of the code snippet above are usually from the times of Windows 7, so maybe it just does not work for whatever reason now?

If my feeling above is correct... What can I do to display the app size while still using NSIS? Seems pretty trivial but that has eaten already several hours of my time with no success on googling a modern solution (except of ones with MSI but I would like to avoid switching).



Not present in your code but I assume you are setting the required DisplayName and UninstallString values as well in the same key?

EstimatedSize is documented here and its reason for existing is detailed here.
This entry has been supported for 25 years but it is only a hint and Microsoft is free to ignore it in their countless rewrites of the Settings app.
Test your installer on Windows 8 or older or try a 3rd-party uninstaller app if you want to verify that you are setting the value correctly...
